# easyui-dialog : is it possible to change the labels/textbox visibility using a dropbox list and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using easyui-dialog to open a window with textbox and label when I press on a button on my page. The code is working and looks like :

```js
     <script type="text/javascript">

      var url;

      function newEvent(){

       $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Nouvel Événement');

       $('#fm').form('clear');

       url = 'save_event.php';

      }

      function editEvent(){

       var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');

       if (row){

        $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Modifier l\'événement');

        $('#fm').form('load',row);

        url = 'edit_event.php?id='+row.id;

       }

      }

      function saveEvent(){


       $('#fm').form('submit',{

        url: url,

        onSubmit: function(){

         return $(this).form('validate');

        },

        success: function(result){

         var result = eval('('+result+')');

         if (result.errorMsg){

          $.messager.show({

           title: 'Error',

           msg: result.errorMsg

          });

         } else {

          $('#dlg').dialog('close');  // close the dialog

          $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data

         }

        }

       });

      }

      function deleteEvent(){

       var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');

       if (row){

        $.messager.confirm('Confirmation','Êtes-vous certain de vouloir supprimer cet événement?',function(r){

         if (r){

          $.post('delete_event.php',{id:row.id},function(result){

           if (result.success){

            $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data

           } else {

            $.messager.show({ // show error message

             title: 'Erreur',

             msg: result.errorMsg

            });

           }

          },'json');

         }

        });

       }

      }
```

```html
  <div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:400px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px"

       closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons" resizable="true">

      <div class="ftitle">Gestion des événements</div>

      <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>

       <div class="fitem">

        <label>Événement</label>

        <input id="evenement" name="evenement" class="easyui-textbox">

       </div>

       <div class="fitem">

        <label>Objet:</label>

        <input name="objet" class="easyui-textbox">

       </div>

       <div class="fitem">

        <label>Filtre:</label>

        <input name="filtre" class="easyui-textbox"  >

       </div>

       <div class="fitem">

        <label>rotation</label>

        <input name="rotation" class="easyui-textbox" type="text" value="">

       </div>


          


      </form>





     </div>

     <div id="dlg-buttons">

      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton c6" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="saveEvent()" style="width:90px">Enregistrer</a>

      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')" style="width:90px">Annuler</a>

     </div>
```

this is working well. Now, I have a dropbox list menu in my page, and I'm using a onchange="javaFunction()" to do some stuff. Now, what I wish to do is to change the visibility of the textbox/labels of the easyui-dialog with the function called by my dropbox list.

For exemple, let's say that I have 6 labels and 6 textbox. If the selected option is 1, I want to show label/textbox 1-2 only and hide 3-4-5-6. If the option is 2, I want to show label/textbox 3-4 and hide the others.

I want trying something like :

```js
function(){
var txtbox1=document.getElementById('txtbox1');
    txtbox1.style.display='none';
}
```

but it's not working... I'm not sure how to make that

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to do it. I just gave an ID to my  where the label and textbox were and used :

```js
document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none";
```

and it's working.